# Weekly date range

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to make a weekly range date for selected date which is captured when i clicked a date on calendar . This is the code that i've made.

```
package com.cc.cielo.backingbean.timesheet;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;


import com.cc.cielo.backingbean.BaseBackingBean;
import com.cc.cielo.managedbean.timesheet.TimesheetManagedBean;

@ManagedBean(name = "timesheetBackingBean")
@RequestScoped
public class TimesheetBackingBean extends BaseBackingBean<TimesheetManagedBean> {


public String createDateRange() {

    Date selDate = this.getManagedBean().getSelectedDate();

    return null;
}

public TimesheetBackingBean(){


}

}
```

```
 <p:column colspan="2" >
 </p:column>
 <p:column colspan="7">
    <p:panelGrid style="width:100%">
    <p:row style="color: ##bfbfbf">
    <p:column style="width:20%">
        <p:button icon="ui-icon-triangle-1-w" disabled="false">
        <f:param name="productId" value="10" />
        </p:button>
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width:60%;  text-align:center">
        <h:outputLabel value="#{timesheetBackingBean.createDateRange}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width:20%; text-align:right">
        <p:button icon="ui-icon-triangle-1-e" disabled="false">
        <f:param name="productId1" value="10" />
        </p:button>
    </p:column>
    </p:row>
    </p:panelGrid>
 </p:column>



 <p:column colspan="7" style="text-align: right;">
 <p:calendar id="event" value="#{timesheetBackingBean.managedBean.selectedDate}" showOn="button" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mask="true">
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{timesheetBackingBean.createDateRange}" />
 </p:calendar>
 </p:column>
</p:row>
        </f:facet>
```

now i want to paste the weekly range from the date i've choosed into that output label.

Comment: Pasting it? Like in ctrl-v?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some research on google . i found my answer for my question.

```
public String createDateRange() {

        Date selDate = this.getManagedBean().getSelectedDate();     
        Date date = new Date();
        Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
        c.setTime(selDate);
        c.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
        int i = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - c.getFirstDayOfWeek();
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, -i);
        Date start = c.getTime();
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
        Date end = c.getTime();
        System.out.println(start + " - " + end);
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String formatted = format1.format(start);
        String formatted2 = format1.format(end);

        this.getManagedBean().setDateRange(formatted + " - " + formatted2);

        return null;
    }


    <p:column style="width:60%;text-align: center;">
        <h:outputLabel id="dateRange" value="#{timesheetBackingBean.managedBean.dateRange}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width:20%; text-align:right">
        <p:button icon="ui-icon-triangle-1-e" disabled="false">
        <f:param name="productId1" value="10" />
        </p:button>
    </p:column>
    </p:row>
    </p:panelGrid>
 </p:column>



 <p:column colspan="7" style="text-align: right;">
 <p:calendar id="event" value="#{timesheetBackingBean.managedBean.selectedDate}" imediate="true" showOn="button" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mask="true">
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{timesheetBackingBean.createDateRange}" update="dateRange" />
 </p:calendar>
 </p:column>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to the answer and format the code a little (split xhtml and java). And also improve the question since 'pasting' it is a totally weird term in this context